# How do the slows from Shadow Slash stack with multiple Living Shadows?

Tags: league-of-legends

From the tooltip:

"Living Shadow: Overlapping Shadow Slashes striking the same enemy deal no additional damage but will incur an increased slow of 30 / 37.5 / 45 / 52.5 / 60% and restore energy."

Is this a flat amount for both 1 Shadow + Zed and 2 Shadows + Zed? Or is the slow percentage different for 1 or 2 shadows?

Answer (score 3):

It's a flat amount.

An enemy hit with a single shadow slash from a shadow will be slowed by 20 / 25 / 30 / 35 / 40%, and an enemy hit by multiple shadow slashes, no matter the amount will be slowed by 30 / 37.5 / 45 / 52.5 / 60%.